# Why did Yoda save Anakin and Obi-Wan instead of finishing Dooku on Geonosis?

Tags: star-wars

Last I recalled, it is Yoda's quote:

> Train yourself to let go of everything you fear to lose.

It has been mentioned lots of times in the canon that attachment is forbidden for a Jedi. While newbies were little bit "flexible" in this regard, how could Yoda, the grandmaster and the most powerful Jedi, not adhere to this? Why did Yoda save Anakin and Obi-Wan on Geonosis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yoda made a tactical choice based on the losses the Jedi had already suffered that day. Given that the options were either losing two of their Omega-level Jedi (on top of the dozens already killed) versus stopping Dooku, he didn't even need to hesitate.

> **No decision was necessary. *Too many Jedi have we lost today*.** Yoda bent his mind toward the crane, concentrating. The crane stopped abruptly in midair as if it had landed on some invisible table. Slowly, Yoda moved the crane away from Obi-Wan and Anakin, to an empty part of the hangar where it could settle safely to the ground.
>
> ...
>
> Behind him, he sensed the engines of the Solar Sailer start, then felt them fade into the distance. **The Count had escaped. But Anakin and Obi-Wan were still alive.
>   For now, that was enough.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Attack of the Clones: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: Omega-level Jedi? One was still a padawan..

Comment: @Endgame - One of the most powerful of his generation, albeit under-trained.